# Apply custom component's id attribute to an internal input element

Tags: angular

I've created a custom Angular component, which is basically a wrapper around an input element with some attributes.
I want this internal input element to be focused when a label element with a **for** attribute, pointing to the **id** attribute of the custom component, is clicked.

```html
<label for="some-id">Label text</label>
<my-custom-element id="some-id"></my-custom-element>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-element',
  template: '<input type="text" />'
})
```

Is it possible to move the **id** attribute along with its' value to an internal element (e.g. the input element)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to achieve what I was looking for.

I've added the following code to MyCustomElementComponent:

```js
@Input() id?: string = ''

constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, private _elementRef: ElementRef) { ... }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._renderer.removeAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'id')
}
```

Of course, the template became:

```html
<input type="text" [id]="id" />
```

Now the component works with:

```html
<my-custom-element id="some-id-literal"></my-custom-element>
<my-custom-element id="{{someIdVar}}"></my-custom-element>
<my-custom-element [id]="'some-id-literal'"></my-custom-element>
<my-custom-element [id]="someIdVar"></my-custom-element>
```

One thing to note is that the **second scenario** retains the binding, even tho the **id** attribute is removed from the custom element - changing **someIdVar** will update the custom element's id property's value. The **first two scenarios** were not covered by [mast3rd3mon's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48881646/revisions), since the **id** attribute remained on the custom element too. His updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48881646/3725009) uses a non-standard **passedId** attribute instead of **id**.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `@Input()` within the custom element class like so, also changing the input name might help:

```
export class MyCustomElement {
    @Input() passedId: string;
    @Input() value: any;
    //other code here
}
```

Then change your template in the custom element to:

```
<input [id]="passedId" [value]="value" type="text" />
```

And then the selector:

```
<my-custom-element passedId="some-id"></my-custom-element>
```

Or swap to ngmodel if you want 2 way databinding

Comment: This doesn't work properly, unless I change `<my-custom-element id="some-id">` to `<my-custom-element [id]="'some-id'">`. Using the former just duplicates the id attribute on both `my-custom-element` and `input`.
I would prefer using the former syntax.